# Cancelling async state changes on dialog close

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with Vue and have a dialog that fetches some data and then renders it when complete. However, if the user manually closes the dialog before the fetch completes, I would like to then ignore all state updates from the async call, to avoid bugs caused by them then immediately opening the dialog again.

Is there a cleaner way to handle this problem? Checking a token three times in separate blocks seems pretty ugly to me. Or am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

```
// A token on the Vue component instance for the most recently async call 
globalToken = null;

private async fetchData() {
    const token = new Object();
    try {
      isFetching = true;
      globalToken = token;

      await fetchSomeData();

      // No side effects if our async token has been revoked
      if (token === globalToken) {
        doStuff();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      if (token === globalToken) {
        displayError();
      }
    } finally {
      if (token === globalToken) {
        this.isFetching = false;
      }
    }
  }

openDialog() {
  fetchData();
}

closeDialog() {
  isFetching = false;
  // Revoke the token for any pending requests
  globalToken = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a generator to accomplish something similar to what you want. An example is below:

```
function* fetchData() {
  let abort = false;

  yield (async() => {
      fetchSomeData().then((data) => {

        if (abort) {
          console.log("aborting")
          return;
        }

        console.log("proceeding")
        doStuff();
      })
  })();

  yield abort = true;
}

const sequence = fetchData();

function openDialog() {
  // This will fire the first yield in the generator, calling your async function
  sequence.next()
}

function  closeDialog() {
  // This will fire the second yield in the generator, setting your flag 
  sequence.next()
}
```

This could allow you to encapsulate your 'abort' flag into a context that you could use to bail out, or do whatever else it is you need to do. Hope that's helpful.